# Which TextField was selected in custom-Cell TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue, custom-cell

Using Swift4, iOS11.1, Xcode9.1,

Doing a segue from a tableView, I try to figure out how to detect which of the two TextFields (in my custom cell) was touched by the user. My custom-Cell tableView has two TextFields as can be seen in the picture below:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
// tableView delegation-method:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMyNextVC", sender: cell)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToMyNextVC" {

        let newVC = segue.destination as! MyNextViewController

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        print(indexPath?.row)  // !!!!!! The cell-row is correct

        let cell = sender as! MyCustomTableViewCell
        newVC.someTextProperty1 = cell.firstTextFiled.text!  // works well
        newVC.someTextProperty2 = cell.secondTextFiled.text!  // works well

        // !!!! BUT HOW DO I GET WHICH OF THE TWO TEXTFIELDS WAS TOUCHED ?????????

        // newVC.someTextProperty3 = ??????? text of touched TextField ???????

    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should register a tap event on a textField inside your MyCustomTableViewCell class and then delegate which textField was tapped back to your viewController.

But an easier solution is just to use two different cells for two different textfields.

Comment: Thanks for the two ideas - I'll give it a shot !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (somehow triggered by Demosthese hint):

1.) Inside the custom-cell:  calling a cell-configure method (assigning the tag of each textField (or labels acuatally in my case now...)

```
func configureCell(tag: Int) {

    // assign tag (later used to expand / collapse the right cell)
    self.fristTextField.tag = 1
    self.secondTextField.tag = 2

    self.firstTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.secondTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

2. inside the custom-cell: define a touchesBegan method reacting to the tag taht is touched and assigning a "tagNrTouched"-property

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

       super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
       let touch: UITouch = touches.first!

       if (touch.view?.tag == self.firstTextField.tag) {
           self.tagNrTouched = 1
       } else if (touch.view?.tag == self.secondTextField.tag) {
            self.tagNrTouched = 2
       }
   }
   ```
3. Inside the tableView, react to this property just before segue'ing:

   ```
   // tableView delegation-method:
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
   {
       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMyNextVC", sender: cell)
   }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       if segue.identifier == "goToMyNextVC" {

           let newVC = segue.destination as! MyNextViewController

           let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
           print(indexPath?.row)  // !!!!!! The cell-row is correct

           let cell = sender as! MyCustomTableViewCell
           newVC.someTextProperty1 = cell.firstTextFiled.text!  // works well
           newVC.someTextProperty2 = cell.secondTextFiled.text!  // works well

           // HERE IS THE FINAL SOLUTION: REACTING ACCORDING TO THE TAG-NR
           if (cell.tagNrTouched == 1) {
                textSearchVC.searchText = cell.firstTextField.text!
           } else if (cell.tagNrTouched == 2) {
                textSearchVC.searchText = cell.secondTextField.text!
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: you can assign tag to entire cell not to single element in method func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) when dequeuing and then send it with delegate method.

Comment: I want to distinguish which element was touched inside one custom cell - therefore assignment to a single element (and not entire cell). Or do you have a code-example of what you mean exaclty ?

Comment: Sorry didn't get the problem...
I bit confused why not using buttons and delegate to view controller when clicked instead have text field?